# Can I reserve memory (set min memory) for Windows Job Objects?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory

I know I can use `JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION` to set the memory cap for a Windows job object. But how do I reserve memory(set min memory) for a job object? I'm not talking about the process working set min, but the memory for the job object.

Comment: Start reading at [To set limits for a job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#job_limits_and_notifications).

Comment: The operating system is responsible for allocating memory for the job object itself.  You don't need to worry about it.